# Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI in the etherscan.io

Tags: web-services

Recently I worked on the problem of the verifying Contract Code, you can know more details about this problem by accessing this link: https://etherscan.io/verifyContract2

I've confirmed that all the information I put into the form is correct：

[image] 
BUT every time I clicked the "Verify And Publish" button, I got this result:

[image]
I've also looked over the compiled information in the Solidity IDE: 
[image]

Someone know where's the problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off optimization. The parameters just don't match when compiling

Comment: Some more explanation to the answer would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and was looking for solutions everywhere, unfortunately I couldn't find anything, but I managed to solve it by doing this:

When you copy your solidity code, in my case I was using Remix. At the very top of the file you have the version something like:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
```

I figured out that if I specify one version only, for example:

```
pragma solidity 0.7.0;
```

And paste rest of the code in https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/ this is where I validate the contract. At the very beginning when they ask you about the version, you should specify solidity 0.7.0 so that they match. This solved my problem, hope it works for you too.

My problem was that when I start the validation process, I always chose the lates version but my contract was in fact supporting from 0.7 until 0.9 which was probably causing the confusion, but after specifying only one specific, it worked.